# Live DOM filtering with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, filter

I have written some JS Code which filters all images which are bigger than a specified size.
The filtered DOM is connected to a click event.

```
var largeImages = allImages.filter(function(){  
    return ($(this).width() > 70) || ($(this).height() > 70)  
});
```

But now I also add some pictures to the DOM with AJAX. These pictures have the size to get through that filter but currently aren't filtered because they are added after the DOM was filtered.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is there any "live" filter function in jQuery which filters the DOM live and appends also new added elements to the array?
2. If this function does not exist. How can I observe the  for DOM Changes so I can run this filter again?

**UPDATE**: I *have no opportunity* to bind to the event which adds the photos.
I am working on a Chrome Extension which gives some options to work with the photos.

Comment: Can you not just filter after you have added the photos?

Comment: There is a `live`, it's `on` but you have to use it for future events. jQuery docs sufficiently explain how.

Comment: What is changing the DOM?

Comment: By the way, you should need to use `on('load',...)` for each image so that you can successfully get naturalWidth and naturalHeight - $(this).width() may not be the actual width of the image.

Comment: Also what does filter actually do? Just maintain the `largeImages` collection?

Comment: Sadly I am not able to filter after the images have added. Im programming a Chrome Extension which does something with that images. @Fresheyeball yes, the filter only maintain the `largeImages` collection.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to monitor dom changes to re-run your filter, AND are only targeting chrome (this is about a chrome extension), then you can use DOM mutation observers

- http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Then when the dom changes you can re-run your filter. Something like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
    // run your filter here
});
observer.observe(document);
```

Comment: @Reflic if that works out, don't forget to hit that green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind on the event that adds the new images, ie the callback function of your AJAX call.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment as to what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: Please leave comments in the comments section. People who could post a complete answer may skip this question because it shows in the list as having an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a live `nodeList`, and then access that variable; for example:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Will continually keep track of the images, including new images added to the document. Of course, this approach means you have to filter that `nodeList` each time you add another `img` to the page. While this is possible, the corollary is that you might as well simply reselect the relevant elements as you add them to the page. However, one approach:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
$('#addImage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<img />', {
        'src' : 'http://placekitten.com/150/150/',
        'height' : '150px',
        'width' : '150px'
    }).insertAfter('#count');
    $('#count').text(function(){
        // using Array.prototype.filter() to filter the array:
        return [].filter.call(images, function(a){
            return a.naturalWidth > 70;
        }).length;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8NQ9e/2/).

But the same could be achieved with the following (simply reselecting the `img` elements after the addition):

```
$('#addImage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<img />', {
        'src' : 'http://placekitten.com/150/150/',
        'height' : '150px',
        'width' : '150px'
    }).insertAfter('#count');
    $('#count').text(function(){
        return $('img').filter(function(){
            return this.naturalWidth > 70;
        }).length;
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8NQ9e/1/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).